# Eclipse Maven Build Error

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-tool-suite

I am beside myself with this error and can't make any progress until I get past this issue.

I have the latest STS (Spring Tool Source) 3.7.1 specifically for Eclipse Mars 4.5.1.   I deleted all my old versions of STS, and deleted my old .eclipse file as well since I wanted this to be a fresh install.  I also went into my c:\Users\Tom Holmes\AppData folders and removed all traces of 'Spring Tool Suite'.

I installed the new latest STS 3.7.1 for Eclipse (Mars) 4.5.1 and pulled down the latest Subclipse for the Eclipse (Mars) 4.5.1.  I opened to my old work space which was fine before, and now whenever I try to use STS to run a maven build I get the error listed below.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Holmes.sts-3.7.1.RELEASE.configuration.org.eclipse.osgi.25.0..cp.;.C:.Users.Tom
```

I have tried everything I can think of to re-loading the projects into a new workspace, to deleting the projects and re-downloading them.

Ultimately I find in the workspace .metadata plugins directory under m2e.eclipse.core   there are no lifecycle mappings?    Does that matter?
How can I re-create this, or is this more of a maven/sts problem?

Comment: What's with all the down votes?    Funny how when I get a downvote, I find other people who have had the same problem and could benefit from that knowledge.

Comment: I think it maybe has to do with the title of your post; it's quite general.

Comment: I added a little bit more information to this, so hopefully this will make a difference.   I spent an 8 hour day yesterday trying to fix this issue ... usually, I have never, and don't know anyone who has ever had this much of an issue with Eclipse or STS before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, here is what I found ... Since STS 3.7.1, specifically for Eclipse (Mars) 4.5.1 was the issue ... I tried several other versions of STS.

I tried STS 3.7.0 for Eclipse (Mars) 4.5.1 which does work.  When I installed this, I immediately got notified that there was an update ready.  The update was specifically for the m2e Maven-Eclipse Integration.

I also tried 3.7.0 for Eclipse (Juno?) 4.2.2 which also does work, and again this was looking for an update, and again was for m2e Maven-Eclipse Integration.

My feeling is that, specifically STS 3.7.1 for Eclipse (Mars) 4.5.1 was broken as far as the m2e plugin.   Since the m2e changes are embedded in this latest version, something must not have been right.  The other versions that I downloaded and installed all worked fine.  For any of these versions, there was this upgrade for the m2e (Maven-Eclipse) integration plugin ... but in this case, the update worked.

You know, I like STS, I think it works great.  After updating several times, like anything else, it can get "jinky" and then I decide that maybe I should just download a new fresh copy of the tool which usually works great.

Clearly pulling this update into the latest version just didn't mesh well.  But now I am up and running, and hopefully SpringSource will fix this issue.

I really hope this helps someone else out.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing a regular Eclipse distribution and then installing STS as a plugin. There should be plenty of instructions online that explain how to do it. I've been using this approach for years and never had any problems.

Comment: I am on a Windows environment and when I download the Eclipse 64 bit, it is an EXE ... so I am not sure if it does a Windows install, or is it just unzipping the file?    What I like about STS is that for Windows, Mac, or Linux, it's just a zip file I can unzip ... and provided I have Java installed, just runs great.